# Fill array of length 5 with the digits of a 5 digit number

Tags: c#, arrays

I want an algorithm that will fill an array of Length 5 with the digits of a 5 digit number. E.g. if the given number is 45678 the array will have the contents |4|5|6|7|8|.

The language that I'm using is C#.

My code:

```
int[] matrix = new int[5]; 
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a 5 digit number: ", i); 
    matrix[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
} 
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine(matrix[i]); 
}
```

Comment: We're not a 'free coding service'. we're here to help you, not do it for you!

Answer (score 1):

=Is this what you expected ?
You can reverse the order by reversing the last for loop

```
        int[] matrix = new int[5];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a 5 digit number: ");
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
        for (int i = matrix.Length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            matrix[i] = number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
        //for (int i = matrix.Length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(matrix[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Copy this and see if this is what you wanted .. AND THEN try to wrap your head around this otherwise you'll never learn it !

Comment: First of all i want to thank you for your time to help me. Second, i just start to learn c# and sometimes i confused.For the reverse output i must change the for parenthesis?

Comment: I added some comment to show you what i meant with reverse the loop. With the first reverse you change the order of the input with the second you change the order of the output. try for yourself to see what happens.

Comment: Although the first solution that you post to me it runs and the output is 54321, when i reverse the loop it crashes! the output must be 12345

Comment: sorry my bad. now it should work with the -1. Arrays begin to count by 0 so the length has to be substracted by -1. After 3 changes by me now it should work

Comment: no prob! but the result is still wrong! it displays 5432 instead of 12345. Which part of the code must change to do the exactly the same as the first one but reversed?

Comment: I changed the above code example now, so that it exactly fits your description.

Comment: Thank you for your time once again! It runs perfect! Can you please advice me to choose a good book for C#? Thanks again sir!

Comment: Sorry i don't know any english books on C# since i am from germany and the "fanbase" is broad enough here ;). If the answer was helpfull consider voting for it and accepting it as correct answer

Comment: OK! I accept it as correct answer but i can't vote it because i need 15 reputation!! And i don't have 15

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method to get the result:

```
    String sInput = "45678";
    int[] ResArr = new int[sInput.Length];
    for (int iPos = 0; iPos < sInput.Length; iPos++)
    {
        ResArr[iPos] = Convert.ToInt32 (sInput.Substring (iPos, 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you, but I will give you a couple of hints...

The String class has a method called Format which can be used gain a string represenation of the five digit number, even accounting for leading zeros.

It also has a ToCharArray method - and Chars, like everything else in .Net, have a ToString method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a 5 digit number: ");
        var sInput = Console.ReadLine(); // Reads all digits at once

        // Check whether the input is a valid number
        int nTest;
        if (!int.TryParse(sInput, out nTest))
        {
             // invalid input: do something specific here (return, alert user, ...)
        }

        //-- Digits extraction starts here
        var acDigits = sInput.ToCharArray(); // Stores all the digits separately
        var anDigits = new int[acDigits.Length]; // Allocates the target array (matrix of int)
        // for each digit within the source text
        for (var ixDigit = 0; ixDigit < acDigits.Length; ixDigit++)
        {
            // Take the digit char, subtracts '0', stores the value
            anDigits[ixDigit] = acDigits[ixDigit] - '0';
        }
        //-- Digits extraction ends here

        // output
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The number is {0} digits long", anDigits.Length));
        // for each stored digit
        for (int ixDigit = 0; ixDigit < anDigits.Length; ixDigit++)
        {
            Console.Write("|" + anDigits[ixDigit].ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("|");
```

This code saves the digits into **anDigits**. It then outputs them as per your result example.

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's split up the task. You already know how to read/write a number. Your problem is about reading this number into an int array. So here is one way to do it:

```
string number = "45678";
int[] result = number.ToCharArray().Select(
    c => (int)char.GetNumericValue(c)).ToArray();
```

[`GetNumericValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k33ktz(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `-1` as n-th value of the array, if n-th character could not be parsed.